# jQuery/Ajax | Test If AJAX Is Passing Variables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a plugin called X-Editable where its a click to edit AJAX request. I so far have gotten the plugin to function and show the edit stuff, but when I go to change the content, I refresh the page and the content never changed. You can set the URL to send the AJAX request, is there any way I can change the URL so I can fire a function and some how check that my $_POST variables are getting sent through? The POST variables being sent through are $_POST["value"], and $_POST["pk"]

How to set the URL

```
('#username').editable({
url: '/post.php',
});
```

Overall, how can I make the URL a function that will let me know if my POST data is getting sent out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use firefox firebug tool to see what data is getting posted. You can leave breakpoints on where ajax calls are being made and see what values are being sent